# Spring Cloud Kubernetes Configuration Watcher with Notification Recipient Not Based on Secret Name

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I've recently heard about [Spring Cloud Kubernetes Configuration Watcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher) in the spring-cloud-kubernetes project. As I understand it, it allows Spring Boot apps that expose the actuator/refresh endpoint to be notified of a change to a ConfigMap or Secret and update accordingly at runtime - no app restart - that sounds brilliant. But the documentation mentions that:

> the Configuration Watcher will take the name of the ConfigMap or Secret
> and send a notification to the application with that name

I was wondering, is there a way to have the notification sent to apps with different names than the Secret? For example, if I have a Secret called auth-server-secret that is shared by a number of microservices with different names, how can I get Spring Cloud Kubernetes Configuration Watcher to notify them all? It would be nice if the notification could be sent based on a label or an annotation. Is that possible? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the mechanism?

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: I have the same question. In my case, I have a Spring Cloud Kubernetes microservice that loads properties from multiple ConfigMaps across multiple namespaces. I've got the Spring Cloud Kubernetes Configuration Watcher automatically refreshing properties that are updated in a ConfigMap that is named the same as my ```spring.application.name```, but I want the ability to update a ConfigMap that has a different name/namespace and have its properties automatically refreshed in my microservice.

Comment: Anyone have any updates regarding this post? Hopefully this feature will be included in an upcoming release of Spring Cloud Kubernetes Configuration Watcher.

Comment: @KeithBennett spring-cloud-kubernetes contributor here. SO is not entirely accurate for such requests. can this be moved to GitHub page of the project? You will get a lot more attention there